# Getting error can not compile module unless --module flag is provided. so not able to create instance of this class in another ts file

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, typescript1.8, typescript1.5

```
export module FilterBar {
export class Filter {
    objData: any;
    distinctAreas: string[];
    distinctRegions: string[];
    distinctSubRegions: string[];
    distinctAreasApplied: string[];
    distinctRegionsApplied: string[];
    distinctSubRegionsApplied: string[];
    call = 0;
    static selectedFilterData: any;
}
```

I want to create an object of this class in another typescript file. For that I am using **export to module** but I am getting the mentioned error.